# Codenameone get time

Tags: time, clock, codenameone

Is there a method in codename one for getting the system's time? Like, what hour it is in the device. Also, I'd like to get the day of the week. Because I want to make a program that constantly runs a clock, and it compares int variables with the current hour, and string variables with the week day. Is there a way to do it? I'm pretty new in programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will return the time. `Date`, `TimeZone` and `java.util.Calendar` are all available just like in standard Java.

Comment: how can I get minutes from it?
Do I have to calculate it?

Comment: You can if you want to. You can also use the `Calendar` class which has `cal.get()` for minutes.